# Any alternative of 'Camtasia Studio (Screen recording & video editing)' for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to make a video tutorials in Ubuntu. Is there a similar program to `Camtasia Studio` (Screen recording & video editing software) in Windows?

Answer (score 15):

I think you can use Kazam Screencaster for recording purpose and for editing those videos you can use Openshot video editor.

The combination of both will you provide functionality of Camtasia Studio.

**Camtsio Studio = Kazam Screenscaster + Openshot Video Editor**

Comment: its better to say `Kazam Screenscaster + Openshot Video Editor = Camtsio Studio with Minimal features` . thanks

Comment: Kazam is a childish and unprofessional app with full of bugs

Answer (score 9):

Just open your [**Ubuntu Center Software**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSoftwareCenter) (you can open it from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) with this command: `software-center`) and search for *screen record* (for example) and you will find applications like [**Kazam**](https://launchpad.net/kazam), [**RecordMyDesktop**](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) or [**Istanbul**](https://live.gnome.org/Istanbul) which may do very well what you intend.

Here is a video review about Kazam: [OMG Video Review: Kazam Screen Recorder Tool](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/record-screen-linux).

Answer (score 1):

You have several options including gtk-recordMyDesktop (gnome) qt-recordMyDesktop (kde)

There is a full tutorial here : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ScreencastTeam/RecordingScreencasts