# Convert a presentation to video with narration

Tags: sound, video, openoffice.org, presentation

I have an OpenOffice presentation.

I want to create a movie (for YouTube), that shows the slides, with my voice explaining about them.

Is this possible in Ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any alternative of 'Camtasia Studio (Screen recording & video editing)' for Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/298309/any-alternative-of-camtasia-studio-screen-recording-video-editing-for-ubun)

Comment: @Mitch I'm not sure this is a duplicate.. It could be, but MS Office Powerpoint has the ability to export a slideshow as a video file. If the OP is asking whether Impress has that ability as well then this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [recordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) to record whatever is going on in your desktop or in a part of it along with sound. You can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get  install recordmydesktop
```

Another option can be to use a dedicated tool like [Slides 2 Video](http://jslideshow.sourceforge.net/), but you will have to add a separate soundtrack.